# When do you need to explicitly call a superclass constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, subclass, superclass

So say I have a subclass that extends a superclass. In what scenarios do I need to explicitly type `super()` to get the superclass constructor to run?

I'm looking at an example in a book about abstract classes and when they extend it with a non-abstract subclass, the subclass's default constructor is blank and there's a comment that says the superclass's default constructor will be called. At the same time I've also seen instances on here where someone's problem was not explicitly calling `super()`.

Is the distinction from calling the superclass's default/non-default constructor from the subclass's default/non-default constructor?

Comment: Is it me or does none of the answers address the question "why do you need to call a superclass' constructor in a subclass"

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You *never* need just

```
super();
```

That's what will be there if you don't specify anything else. You *only* need to specify the constructor to call if:

- You want to call a superclass constructor which has parameters
- You want to chain to another constructor in the same class instead of the superclass constructor

You claim that:

> At the same time I've also seen instances on here where someone's problem was not explicitly calling super().

Could you give any examples? I can't imagine how that's possible...

Comment: Yea I should've been more clear. It was super(with arguments). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You are right. But about this: 'At the same time I've also seen instances on here where someone's problem was not explicitly calling super().' This happens when parent constructor does not have a noarg constructor. In that case if you don't explicitly call super() you will get an error.

Comment: @ACV: Explicitly calling `super()` won't work there either. Calling a superconstructor *with a non-empty argument list* would work, but just using `super()` wouldn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sometimes see a lot of `super()`s in the code I work with. I do almost clinically remove these whenever I see them. However, I cannot help wonder if there is a reason why they are there. Would you be able to think of a case where you actually want these no args constructors?

Comment: @patrik: Well there's a difference between requiring the constructor to be present, and requiring an explicit delegation to the parameterless super-constructor. The latter is a matter of style - whether you prefer to be explicit/obvious or brief.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't explicitly call a super constructor the argument less constructor (super()) will be called. This means you have to call a specific constructor yourself if there's no reachable argument-less constructor of the super class.

But often enough you want a different constructor anyways even if you could use the default constructor - depends on your code.

Also note that if no constructor is declared the compiler generates a public default constructor automatically, but as soon as you write your own constructor this does not happen anymore.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. If in my superclass, I have one constructor and it's not the default constructor(say it takes a parameter). Then in my constructor for my subclass I need to explicitly call super(param) because the compiler will no longer generate a default constructor for the super class?

Answer (score 4):

The `super()` method is always called in constructors of sub-classes, even if it is not explicitly written in code.

The only time you need to write it, is if there are several `super(...)` methods in the super-class with different initialization parameters.

Comment: "The only time you need to write it, is if there are several super(...) methods in the superclass with different initialization parameters." Not true. As long as there's a reachable argument less constructor, you can have a hundred other constructors without any problems.