# What does super() mean in a constructor?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

What does the code

```
super();
```

do inside of a constructor?

For example, here is a constructor for my class

```
public abstract class Rectangle extends AbstractShape
{

private double height, width;

// Constructors...  
public Rectangle()
{
    super(); //this is how i inherit that point!
    height = -1;
    width = -1;
}
```

Does it have something to do with super-classes?

Comment: Question was well stated, however. So, I am surprised he now has a negative 7 vote on the question.

Comment: @finneycanhelp: As at:Nirbhay already mentioned, it would have been easy to find an answer to this question by just doing a bit of research (googling)... IMO this is the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: ok. So, in the future the google keywords to use are: super java constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It calls the parent class's constructor

Comment: Is using super class a self declaration even if it is not added in the initialization?

Comment: @DavidDimalanta "If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 3):

It goes to the parent class and calls the constructor.

[This link over at oracle should help](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: super() is a reference which invokes SuperClass Constructor..

Answer (score 1):

The call `super();` explicitly invokes the superclass constructor, here the parameterless constructor for `AbstractShape`.  If this call is not present in a constructor, then Java inserts an implicit `super();` for you.

Quoting the [JLS, section 8.8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor
>   invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the
>   primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins
>   with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of
>   the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It calls the constructor of the superclass.
See the following questions:

- [java when do you need to explicitly call a superclass constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318628/java-when-do-you-need-to-explicitly-call-a-superclass-constructor)
- [When do I use super() in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090834/when-do-i-use-super-in-java)