# Java - Explicit super() in subclass constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, superclass, super

I found some similar topics, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318628/java-when-do-you-need-to-explicitly-call-a-superclass-constructor), but they did not answer my question in entirely. Question is very simple:

Is it a good practice to call the `super()`  in a subclass' constructor? I know of course, that if I do not make it explicitly, a compiler will do it for me, but I'm asking only in context of the best practices. Do you consider invoking `super()` in each subclass' constructor as a "triumph of form over substance" ?

I'm working with code which contains uses strategies, so I see, that for many programmers it does not matter at all... For me it does not matter as well now, but maybe I should change it...

Comment: You **have to** do it if the super class doesn't have a default constructor. For example: `class Fruit{ protected String flavor; public Fruit(String flavor) { this.flavor = flavor; } } class Apple extends Fruit { public Apple() { super("sweet"); } }`. Off topic: `super("sweet")` sounds funny :).

Comment: I never use the empty `super()` because it's simply redundant, but as @LuiggiMendoza says, `super(...)` can be necessary.

Comment: Yes, of course. But I meant only the situation in which super can be omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion explicit super() call is just polluting the code. Default super() call is invented exactly for this purpose - to shorten the code. See SE library source, super() is hardly ever used, eg

```
public HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
   if (initialCapacity < 0)
   ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Good practice?  Call what's necessary to correctly initialize your object.

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    public Foo() { this(""); }
    public Foo(String n) { this.name = n; }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    private int x;
    public Bar(int y) { this("", y); }
    public Bar(String n, int y) {
        super(n);
        this.x = y;
    }
}
```