# What for we need super() in ArrayList constructor?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

this code from ArrayList source:

```
public ArrayList() {
    super();
    this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

this code from AbstractList source:

```
protected AbstractList() {
}
```

What does super() do?

Comment: Do you want to know what `super` does in general, or why `super` is used in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, `super` will invoke its parent constructor with matching arguments.  In this case, because `AbstractList` has an implicit no-arg constructor, we use `super()` with no arguments to invoke the implicit no-arg constructor.

As to *why* - there's really no reason to do it in this case, if there's no requirement to set fields in the parent class.  This may have been a case of an older style of programming.

It does no harm, and it's self-documenting; it's explicit in that it calls its parent's constructor.  Although, I will note that the Javadoc for that constructor calls out its invocation usefulness:

```
/**
 * Sole constructor.  (For invocation by subclass constructors, typically
 * implicit.)
 */
```

You're more likely to see implicit invocations of that constructor than you are explicit.

Comment: Could also be here to anticipate a version where the constructor of  `AbstractList` will actually do something

Comment: Considering that `AbstractList` has been around since 1.2, I genuinely doubt that they were anticipating something with that constructor.  It could also be a legacy holdover.  I'm not sure; I'd have to pull down the source code history to tell you for certain.

Answer (score -1):

`super()` call parent constructor.

`super()` is never needed, however it is not a bad habit to write it, because it is good for readability - it reminds you that parent constructor is called.

See this question [When do you need to explicitly call a superclass constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318628/when-do-you-need-to-explicitly-call-a-superclass-constructor)

Comment: *Never* needed?  You sure about that?

Comment: Well, let me rewrite the answer, I didn't express myself well.

Comment: Edit: after some googling, I'm pretty sure. It's really never needed.

Comment: What if I have a parent class that doesn't have a no-arg constructor?  I'd need to invoke `super` *then*.

Comment: @Makoto Even if the parent do not have a no-arg constructor, `super` will not be required to instanciate the child

Comment: If parent has no no-arg constructor, then you will not compile the code without calling super(parameter). calling super() will not help you and not calling super(parameter) will not help you either. Just tried it in Eclipse.

Comment: I'm talking in general terms.  `super` isn't a method, it's a keyword; there are scenarios in which you do need to use the keyword.

Comment: That interests me. When is it needed?