# When extending a gridview, why need to call super in constructor?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I implemented an expandedGridView like this [Kishanjvaghela's github](https://gist.github.com/Kishanjvaghela/248b86b9e1c9fbcb8cd7) example or the answer of [Raj008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005245/how-to-have-a-gridview-that-adapts-its-height-when-items-are-added) in stack Overflow.

It works fine, but I wonder why does it need to call `super()` in the constructor

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView {
    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
/* more code here */
}
```

If there is no constructor, java must call parent constructor, isn't it ?

Comment: Check this [Why is constructor of super class invoked when we declare the object of sub class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7173019/7666442) and this one [Why do this() and super() have to be the first statement in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318640/7666442)

Comment: extending a class, you have to declare at least one constructor calling parent class constructor. Only if a parent class has the default constructor (with no arguments) you can skip declaring constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because by default(optional) `super()` keyword will call no-arg constructor, So to call argumented constructor of parent class it must to write `super()` keyword with arguments

just see how constructor chaining works